# I can not catch request code

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with the response of my activity. It is a module to react natively. I have this react class and I am trying to get result from my activity. I've tried catching the requestCode like this:

```
    public CameraOpenerModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);

    getReactApplicationContext().addActivityEventListener(new ActivityEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            Log.e("TEST", "listener start event");
            if (requestCode == 9999) {
                Log.e("TEST", "request code ");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

and I open the class intent:

```
    private void openCameraIntent(){

    cameraIntent = new Intent(getReactApplicationContext(), CameraHelpActivity.class);
//    cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
    cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getReactApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 9999,null);
}
```

and another activity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setResult(1111);
    Log.i("ACTIVITY", "finish !!!!!");
    finish();
}
```

Everything is ok. But I'm not catching the request code. Does anybody know why? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(mReactInstanceManager != null){
        mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
}
```